# How to set PageMediaType without using Print Dialog (Print Directly to default Printer) in C# (WinForm)?

Tags: c#

this is my code to compose a page and print it directly without using PrintDialog.now how to change PageMediaType before printing page?

```
private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender,PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //Some Codes that Compose Document for Printing
}   
private void PrintPage()
{
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    printDocument.Print();
}
```